# Nginx ignoring HTTP headers before Host header when using proxy_pass to Apache

Tags: nginx, debian, apache-2.4

When Nginx is sent the following request, Apache is unable to get the "app_version" HTTP header.

I normally use `apache_request_headers()` to get all headers.
I have also examined the contents of `$_SERVER`

```
GET /stuff HTTP/1.0
app_version: 1.0
Host: example.com
```

However, when the following header is sent, `apache_request_headers()` does return the "app_version" HTTP header!

```
GET /stuff HTTP/1.0
Host: example.com
app_version: 1.0
```

The problem is, I am using a 3rd party REST client (Retrofit), and it seems to send the headers in a random order, so I cannot simply fix this by sending the Host header first.  In any case, I don't see why a header with underscores in it, or the order it is placed in, should affect anything.  *(The header format is compatible with the HTTP spec).*  I would like a solution for the current problem, and not a workaround.

I have the following Nginx configuration:

```
underscores_in_headers on;

location / {
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

   proxy_pass_request_headers on;
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

What would be causing this inconsistency?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add

```
proxy_set_header app_version $http_app_version;
underscores_in_headers on;
```

to the configuration.

It might be that only the `underscores_in_headers` setting is enough here.

Comment: Thank  you for the reply.  I already had the underscores_in_headers outside the location element (see above).  However adding it within the element gave `"nginx: [emerg] "underscores_in_headers" directive is not allowed here"`  I also added your proxy_set_header option, which saved fine, but didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Tero Kilkanen is correct. However you must add `underscores_in_headers on;` to the `http` section of the nginx conf, not only to your `server` section.

Nginx cannot know the virtual host to which the request is addressed before parsing the `Host` header. Therefore all headers that are parsed before the `Host` header are parsed in the "context" of the `http` configuration. If you don't have `underscores_in_headers on;` in the `http` configuration all headers that appear before `Host` and contain underscores are deemed invalid and are ignored. Once the `Host` header is parsed the configuration directives that belong to the `server` section corresponding to your request are activated. So if you have `underscores_in_headers on;` at `server`-level the headers appearing after `Host` and containing underscores are not discarded.

Answer (score -1):

Same issue here, with a load balancer that is adding X-Forwarded-For, -Port and -Proto headers before the Host header:

```
$ nc -l 443
GET / HTTP/1.1
X-Forwarded-For: x.x.x.x
X-Forwarded-Port: 443
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
Host: y.y.y.y:443
Connection: keep-alive
```

Nginx just never fills $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for nor $http_x_forwarded_proto which means these are dropped.

Also, using curl to simulate the LB does result in nginx filling this in properly and there, the HOST comes before the x-fwd headers:

```
GET /admin/extra-commands/ HTTP/1.1
Host: x.x.x.x
X-Forwarded-For: 1.2.3.4
```

I think this is a limitation/bug of nginx